# Why flask db upgrade command is running without no response?

Tags: flask, migrate

```
>flask db upgrade
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade 2a733c87e115 -> b5bfaec8048b, empty message
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade b5bfaec8048b -> 59196d7b20a8, empty message
```

My command has been runing for 2hours without any response, what could the problem please?

I've a new column to my model, then i run flask db upgrade to upgrade the db.